# Adding subfloor

Tags: walls, subfloor

I removed a wall in my home while remodeling. There was no subflooring under that wall so it was completely open to the crawlspace. I filled the holes with that spray foam insulation to keep bugs and pests out until I could fix it. My question is how do I put subflooring in there? Do I have to remove the surrounding subfloor so I can have a continuous piece there or is it possible to use some plywood to fill in those sections? It's an L-shape section and so some has supporting floor joists under there and some does not.
Thanks! I appreciate any suggestions.

Comment: Canned spray foam is hideously flammable. Get that out of there when able.

Comment: Unless, of course, it's fire-block foam.

Answer (score 1):

You can piece in plywood strips to fill the space but it needs to be solidly connected to the surrounding subfloor.  Without solid backing and connection these strips can flex and leave a weak spot in your floor.  There are two things that should be done.

1. Add vertically oriented blocking between adjacent floor joists across the open area. This blocking would be at right angles to the floor joists and ideally would be the same height as the joists.
2. In between any blocking cut pieces of 2x4 type framing lumber to run along the sides and ends of the open areas. These can lie flat, half of the width under the existing subfloor and the other half of width extending into the open area.
3. When you install the filler plywood strips screw it down into both the blocking between the joists and along the edges into the flat 2x4s. Make sure to also screw the existing sub-floor into the flat 2x4s. Recommended screw spacing along the edges is 4 to 5 inches apart.